# VBA Find method errors on Excel Mac 2011

Tags: macos, vba, excel

The following method is working just fine in Excel for Windows but on the Mac i get a 448 runtime error "cannot find argument"

```
Set aCell = Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(1).Find(What:=HeaderName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Any ideas?

Comment: it can't work in `Excel for Windows` since your are using `.Activate` property: `Set aCell = ...Find().Activate`

Comment: Sorry just something i tried to get it to work on Mac. Indeed Windows version is without .Activate

Comment: Found the answer.

There is no SearchFormat argument on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Like Paul mentioned, remove `SearchFormat:=False`

```
Set aCell = Worksheets(SheetName).Rows(1).Find(What:=HeaderName, LookIn:=xlValues, _
      LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
      MatchCase:=False).Activate
```